# How to install gensim without pip (firewall issues)

Tags: python, installation, firewall, gensim

All-

I would like to use the gensim library, but unfortunately I can't install it via pip due to the company's firewall. Any advice? Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tedious and only solution then is to download all the dependencies one by one and install them along with gensim.  So, go to pypi and download gensim first and install it, then it might raise errors saying some package is missing or trying to download it.Then, download that specific package and install it via pip by giving path to the downloaded whl or source file